# How to get the "distance by road" in google maps api?

Tags: javascript, google-maps-api-3, geo

If you try get the distance of:

1. Presidente Vargas 817, Centro RJ
2. rua de santana macaé rj

**in Maps v3 API computeDistanceBetween()**, you got **155**566.80511451405...but..

in **maps.google**: [you got: **187** km !!!](http://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=Presidente%20Vargas%20817,%20Centro%20RJ&daddr=rua%20de%20santana%20maca%C3%A9%20rj&hl=pt-BR&ie=UTF8&sll=-22.713122,-43.662291&sspn=0.40664,0.727158&geocode=FQuHov4dPxFt_SmJnKsEXX-ZADHVBu1VyAPHew;Fbajqv4dLG-C_SmrXFb4XDCWADFI0LJdwRJc5w&mra=ls&t=h&z=10)

**UPDATE:** Maps.google returns the distance by road, have a way to get this distance?

Answer (score 3):

The `computeDistanceBetween()` function is giving you a result in meters, as the crow flies.  The maps.google.com example is giving a result in kilometers, as the car drives.  Thus the route is slightly longer.

The actual driving distance between two points will almost never match the shortest possible distance between them.

Comment: have a way to get the "driving distance" in API?